# wronskian for showing linear independent

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, wronskian

Show that the functions $~f_1(x)=e^x,~ f_2(x)=xe^x,~ f_3(x)=x^2 e^x~$ are  linear independent by using Wronskian .

Comment: my sol is 

e^x   ,,,   Xe^x  ,,,    x^2 e^x,,,


e^x ,,,     e^x + Xe^x  ,,,  x^2 e^x +2xe^x ,,,


e^x   ,,,   .......,,,  ......,,, I cannot continue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$W(f_1,f_2,f_3)(x) =\begin{vmatrix}
f_1 & f_2 & f_3 \\ 
f_1' & f_2' & f_3'  \\ 
f_1'' & f_2'' & f_3''   \notag
\end{vmatrix}= \begin{vmatrix}
e^x & xe^x & x^2e^x \\ 
e^x & e^x(x+1) & e^x(2x+x^2)  \\ 
e^x & e^x(x+2) & e^x(2+4x+x^2)   \notag
\end{vmatrix}$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks a lot yes i can